# How to italicize a word being displayed by a web.sitemap

Tags: javascript, html, web.sitemap, initialization

I have a company name that always needs to be italicized.  I have navigation that is driven by my sitemap and I can not figure out how to italicize the word.  The word is always the same, so I thought about some Jscript, but was wondering if I had any other options.  Thank You.

Comment: Could you provide more detail?  Is the sitemap in xml?

Comment: I believe so.  I used the default asp.net sitemap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added character encodings to my sitemap to italicize.  Ex: for < I used &lt

Answer (score 0):

If the sitemap is an XML document than you might use an XSLT stylesheet to print out the content (a little tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).

But without using CSS or tags you can't make a word italic. There is no italic char for each symbol. So in a pure XML document there is no ways to do that.